# How to add camera to Matrix4x4 rotation

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, system.numerics

I am trying to rotate a cube using System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 and SDL2 for graphic output. i have a hard time understanding the Matrix rotation concept.

I can do it, like so:

```
matrix *= Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(deg);
matrix *= Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(deg);
matrix *= Matrix4x4.CreateRotationZ(deg);
```

Then I'm using Vector3.Transform() on the points in the cube and draw lines between them. Looks... alright, it's rotating in place. But how do I get perspective? How to get a camera into the mix?

What about this method:

```
matrix *= Matrix4x4.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(2, 2, 2), (float)rad);
```

I am not sure how I'm supposed to use the vector there, or what it's supposed to do. My cube grows and stretches out weirdly... see pic of when the matrix is applied 10, 45 and 90 degrees on the cube:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hui5jvky7cexciq/10_45_90.png?dl=0

How should I do this properly?

Comment: A linear algebra tutorial for game programmers would be a good place to start; then read about the camera matrix (more specifically the *view* matrix). Scratchapixel has some very nice entry-level tutorials.

Comment: Hmm like this one?

https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrix-introduction

I shall try to read / understand it (seems a bit math-heavy) and report back!

Comment: Not that one (although it will also be necessary later), try [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry) and [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/lookat-function).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that!